# Cannot load SQLite DLL on Windows 7 32bit PC

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I've currently used the System.Data.SQLite DLL in a .NET 4.0 x86 WinForms app. This is causing an issue on one of my client's PCs although I cannot reproduce this bug on my system. Both systems are 32bit Windows 7. How do I solve this? Things I've tried:

- Installing .NET 4.0 (the app is .NET 4)
- Installing all possible VC++ Runtime versions from 2005 to 2012
- Installing [this particular VC++ Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26347) that SQLite needs (fixed a similar issue on my PC)
- Adding the useLegacyRuntime attribute in the app.config XML

The error looks wierd because my app is obfuscated. The app works on my 32-bit PC and on my 64-bit development PC. It fails on a client machine. What can I do to solve this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my SQLite DLL was outdated. I downloaded the latest from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) and rebuilt my app with it. It worked on my PC as well as the client's. I had to install VC++ Runtime 2005 x32 on the Client Machine as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your project, solution explorer expands the Reference section and right click `System.Data.SQLite` then open properties, in the properties window, make sure copy local is set `true` . After that rebuild your project and run your client machine again